# List all date and time between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I need help with my query to list all dates and time between two date and time columns

This is the main table:

| ID | Date_Time | Action_c | Action_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 01-01-2022 13:10:00 | 1 | Start |
| 32221 | 01-03-2022 13:10:00 | 2 | End |

I used CTEs to get the start time and end time in one row

```
WITH start_time AS
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM main 
    WHERE action_c = 1
),
end_time AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM main 
    WHERE action_c = 2
)
SELECT
    start_time.ID,
    start_time.Date_Time AS Start_time,
    end_time.Date_Time AS End_time,
    DATEDIFF(minute, start_time.Date_Time, end_time.Date_Time) AS DateDiff
FROM 
    start_time 
INNER JOIN 
    end_time ON start_time.ID = end_time.ID
```

Results:

| ID | Start_Time | End_time | DateDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 01-01-2022 13:10:00 | 01-03-2022 13:10:00 | 2880 |

But what I actually need is :

| ID | Start_Time | End_time | DateDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 01-01-2022 13:10:00 | 01-02-2022 13:10:00 | 1440 |
| 32221 | 01-02-2022 13:10:00 | 01-03-2022 13:10:00 | 1440 |

Not sure how I can do that without creating any function.

Comment: @Jodrell First table. (added above the code)

Comment: If the END time was on 04 would you expect 2 rows, ie a row for each 24 hour span?

Comment: @Stu Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where I add an ID and the EndTime <> StartTime

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4bc59d96258fd846b04fe27d10997161)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Date_Time] datetime,[Action_c] int,[Action_type] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (32221,'01-01-2022 13:10:00',1,'Start')
,(32221,'01-03-2022 13:10:00',2,'End')
,(99999,'01-01-2022 13:10:00',1,'Start')    -- Added
,(99999,'01-04-2022 10:00:00',2,'End')      -- Added End Time<>Start Time

;with cte1 as ( 
Select ID
      ,DR1  = min(case when Action_C=1 then Date_Time end)
      ,DR2  = max(case when Action_C=2 then Date_Time end)
      ,nDays= datediff(day, min(case when Action_C=1 then Date_Time end),max(case when Action_C=2 then Date_Time end) )
 From  @YourTable
 Group By ID
), cte2 as (
Select Top 1000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
)
Select ID
      ,c.Start_Time 
      ,c.End_Time  
      ,DateDiff   = datediff(minute, c.Start_Time,c.End_Time )
 From  cte1
 Join  cte2 on N< nDays
 Cross Apply ( values ( dateadd(DAY,N,DR1),case when N=nDays-1 then DR2 else dateadd(DAY,N+1,DR1) end ) )C(Start_Time,End_Time)
 Order by ID,Start_Time
```

**Results**

```
ID      Start_Time              End_Time                  DateDiff
32221   2022-01-01 13:10:00.000 2022-01-02 13:10:00.000   1440
32221   2022-01-02 13:10:00.000 2022-01-03 13:10:00.000   1440
99999   2022-01-01 13:10:00.000 2022-01-02 13:10:00.000   1440
99999   2022-01-02 13:10:00.000 2022-01-03 13:10:00.000   1440
99999   2022-01-03 13:10:00.000 2022-01-04 10:00:00.000   1250  -- Note
```